# PyWinAuto : Automating the windows file 'browse' option

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am trying to automate an application using pywinauto. As a part of this,I am trying to get the file path of an excel file as an input from the user from my Python application and trying to automate another application. But the file browser window (of the application to be automated) does not accept file path as an input.

My objective is that it should open the file using the path that is taken from the user using my Python application. I want to automate this window, but I am stuck on this Open window for quite some time.

[image: The window to be automated]

Can someone help me on how I can automate this? I am fairly new to this so any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to automate Excel?  There are MUCH better ways to do that then by hacking keystrokes.

Comment: The application that I am supposed to automate is a huge tool that automates large excel file. It has a number of dependencies. I am trying to just automate that application for multiple files.

Comment: Remember that the file browser dialog is a separate window from the application window.  You'll need to search for the dialog.